# How to keep websocket alive while application is in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services

I have integrated AWS over websocket in my application so that my application get notified whenever actual state of my resource at AWS IoT changed. It is working fine till the application is in foreground.

But when i moved my application to background state , websocket get closed and app didn't get resource change notification. Can anybody let me know how can i keep the websocket alive while application is in background state.

Comment: In your case you might want to use push notification to alert the user/app of changes to a IoT device. This will greatly increase the experience of your app since it will not drain the devices battery.